# USB C ports stopped working (except for charger)

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

I've recently upgraded my Mac OS Version and after a restart the only USB C port working is the one I'm used to charge my computer on

[image]

Did this happened to anyone before?

Comment: Have you tried an SMC reset? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: I did that and worked!